# Removing child by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, dom

Having this JS code:

```
var prompter = (function(){
    var prompt = document.createElement('div');
    /* prompt-related stuff */

    var closeBtn = document.createElement('button');
    /* closeBtn stuff */

    prompt.appendChild(closeBtn);

    this.html = prompt;

    this.show = (function(){
        document.body.appendChild(this.html);
    });

    this.close = (function(){
        document.body.removeChild(this.html);
    });
});
```

If I do

```
    var p = new prompter();
    p.show();
```

It does show the prompter, and if I do `p.close();` it disappears.

BUT what I want is that by clicking the `closeBtn` it indeed closes. I had the idea of adding an `id` to the prompt and then adding the attribute onclick to the button and performing the actions there via the `id`, but that looks really ugly...

Comment: Brilliant question title! I'm sure many parents would love this! lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to the button you made:

```
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", this.close.bind(this));
```